# are there differences between condition in where and condition in on

Tags: sql, optimization

is there a difference between both statements below? 
- logically
- in performance (perhaps depends on the real system (MySQL, Oracle, ...)

```
select * from t1 
join t2 on (t1.id=t2.id) and t1.id > 2 
join t3 on (t2.id=t3.id) and t2.id > 4;

select * from t1 
join t2 on (t1.id=t2.id) 
join t3 on (t2.id=t3.id) 
where t1.id > 2 and t2.id > 4;
```

Comment: Do your database's tools show a difference in execution plan?

Comment: Not if they are `INNER JOINS`, but they will act different if they are in `OUTER JOINS`.

Comment: AN index might  need to be different but I doubt there are differences in performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this across millions of records using orders, but with the same premise:

**Filtering in the join**

```
select *
from dbo.Orders orders
    INNER JOIN dbo.OrderItems orderItems ON orderItems.OrderID = orders.OrderID AND
        orders.OrderDate  > '01/01/2012'
```

**Filtering in the where**

```
select *
from dbo.Orders orders
    INNER JOIN dbo.OrderItems orderItems ON orderItems.OrderID = orders.OrderID
where
    orders.OrderDate > '01/01/2012'
```

**Conclusion**

The execution plans were identical.

**Observation**

Two points: First, this may not yield the same execution plan in all scenarios.  So, as others have mentioned, you should try this out on a case-by-case basis.  Secondly, I would use the 'where' version that distinguishes 'joining' and 'filtering'.  One operation is an artifact of how you've normalized your data.  The 'filtering' component is the desire to see a subset of that data.  So I would keep things in the 'where' clause that are filtering a joined dataset.